# Lenovo Thinkpad Wireless Hard Blocked

Tags: wireless, lenovo, thinkpad, rfkill

Until now my wlan has been working perfectly on a two week old 14.04 install on a brand new E540. It suddenly died on me, couldn't be turned on in **settings > networks** or via <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>.

`rfkill` output:

```
~$ rfkill list all

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> only toggles the soft block, same for `rfkill unblock all`

I'm in need of any method of toggling the hard block on the phy0 Wireless Lan.

Comment: So you want to hard blocking your phy0: Wireless LAN? Or you want to have it back to work?

Comment: I want a way of toggling the hard block in linux

Comment: If you are actually asking about 20.04 (August 2020) and not 14.04 (October 2011), could you update the question so that it contains correct information @caffeinated.tech ?

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled on the solution from a friend who had a similar issue on an old Dell inspiron.
The E540, and probably similar Thinkpad models, automatically turns off the wireless card when an ethernet cable/ usb modem is connected before boot. This functionality is fine for Windows where <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> actually toggles the hard block, but on linux it requires a restart with any LAN connections removed.

So the solution for now is to only connect my 3G modem after boot.

## Update:

If anyone knows how to toggle hard blocked network connections in linux, please to add an answer, this is really just an interim solution that doesn't fix the underlying issue.