# WiFi device is hard blocked

Tags: networking, drivers, wifi-hardware-switch

My WiFi is **hard blocked** according to `rfkill list`. I have tried `rfkill unblock all` (although it's used for soft block/unblock).

I have checked my BIOS settings, and WiFi is not disabled there. I am not even able to turn on the WiFi service through the function key when the OS is loaded. I believe the device is working fine because all indicators blink on boot.

I am using Lenovo Thinkpad. If anyone has any solution, please suggest.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
project-mach@projectmach-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
0:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series 
Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)

--

03:00.0 Network controller [02800]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 
6300 [8086:4238] (rev 3e)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN [8086:1111]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Ouptut of `rfkill list`:

```
project-mach@projectmach-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Where is the output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: Was working on it...

Comment: I did try the black listing stuff before but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu now so there are no changes in any of the configuration file.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/530032/167850

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: Alright I read that thing but the thing is I have not connected my Ethernet cable before booting up my machine.

Comment: I wrote an answer how to disable the blocking module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this thing solved. The hard block issue was due to a button on the lower part of my laptop which was accidentally switched due to which the output of rfkill list showed yes for hard blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-tpacpi.conf <<< "blacklist thinkpad_acpi"
```

and reboot.

It is also possible instead of blacklisting the module set some parameters like `wwan_state` and `dbg_wwanemul`, but it needs some testing.

Comment: Alright I'll just try it.